# What are the implications of using a static member function with pthread_create()?

Tags: c++, multithreading, posix

I'm helping a student with their homework, which is a basic threading exercise. Unfortunately, though they're required to use C++11, they're forbidden from using `std::thread`. I don't see the rationale, but it's not my homework.

Here's the class:

```
class VaccineInfo {
public:
  VaccineInfo(const std::string &t_input_filename):
    input_filename(t_input_filename)
  { }
  VaccineInfo() = delete;

  static void *count_vaccines(void *t_vi);

  int v1_count() { return vaccine_count["v1"]; }
  int v2_count() { return vaccine_count["v2"]; }
  int v3_count() { return vaccine_count["v3"]; }

private:
  std::string input_filename;

  std::map<std::string, int> vaccine_count {
    { "v1", 0 },
    { "v2", 0 },
    { "v3", 0 }
  };

};

void *VaccineInfo::count_vaccines(void *t_vi) {
  VaccineInfo *vi = reinterpret_cast<VaccineInfo*>(t_vi);
  std::ifstream input_file;
  std::string input_line;

  input_file.open(vi->input_filename);
  if (!input_file.good()) {
    std::cerr << "No such file " << vi->input_filename << std::endl;
    return nullptr;
  }

  while (std::getline(input_file, input_line)) {
    vi->vaccine_count[input_line]++;
  }

  return nullptr;
}
```

And here's where `pthreads` comes in.

```
std::vector<std::string> filenames = find_filenames(".");
std::vector<pthread_t> thread_handles;
std::vector<VaccineInfo> vi_vector;

vi_vector.reserve(filenames.size());

for(const std::string &filename : filenames) {
pthread_t tid;
thread_handles.push_back(tid);
vi_vector.emplace_back(VaccineInfo(filename));
pthread_create(
    &thread_handles.back(), nullptr, &VaccineInfo::count_vaccines,
    static_cast<void*>(&vi_vector.back()));
}

for (const pthread_t tid : thread_handles) {
pthread_join(tid, nullptr);
}
```

It's a pretty basic exercise, except for how much fluff you have to do to get the old and the new to play nice. And that's what's got me wondering - does using a static member method as the `start_routine` argument to `pthread_create` have any undesirable side effects? I know static member variables and functions don't "belong" to any objects, but I normally think of static variables as being one-per-class, regardless of the number of objects. If there's only one copy of the static member function, as well, that seems like you'd be shooting yourself in the foot for parallelization.

Would it just be better, in this case, to make `vaccine_count` public and make `count_vaccines()` a global function?

Do hit me with whatever detail you can muster; I'm very curious. =) And, as always, thank you all for your time and effort.

Comment: This is a pretty standard way of dealing with threads or other callbacks that can't use a member function directly. You pass the *this* pointer as a context and use it to access the members of the object inside the static function.

Comment: What do you mean by "there's only one copy of the static member function"? It's code, there is only one copy of it anyway. Objects don't get their own copy of a member function, they all call the same function with different this* pointers. You just do that explicitly here by handing a pointer to the object to a static function. It'll work fine and as @RetiredNinja said it's a standard way of doing this. Won't affect parallelization at all. The important thing is to give each thread a different object to work with, which you do.

Comment: pthreads is a C library, not a C++ library. `pthread_create()` takes a C-style function pointer for its callback. It has no concept of C++ classes/objects at all.  However, a `static` class method in C++ is compatible with a C function pointer. A pthreads callback takes a user-defined pointer as input, which can be used in C++ to pass an object pointer into the `static` method. This is the *preferred* way of dealing with C callbacks in a C++ OOP way (but it is not the *only* way).

Comment: The OP actually demonstrates one of the down-sides of teaching people to use standard library facilities first - they believe the standard library is the lowest level way of doing things, rather than (as is often actually the case) an higher level set of facilities that are implemented using a set of lower-level, possibly platform specific, functions.   In this case, abstractions like `std::thread` are implemented (on some host systems) using pthreads and, thanks to having learned the standard library way of doing things, the OP doesn't understand how the pthreads layer works.

Comment: @dabo42 that's excellent clarification; thank you. I suppose I knew that on some conceptual level, but my concern was that a static member function might not be able to be called simultaneously. Being reminded that code isn't actually instructions, though, I'm guessing that's not the case. =)

Comment: @RemyLebeau I know they're from different paradigms, but I'm glad to know I chose a preferred method when setting it up.

Comment: @Peter I learned C and POSIX libraries many years before I started with C++, and it was several more years before std::thread became a thing. What I don't understand is what happens on individual cores when you start mixing the above traits. What's at the core of my wondering is `static`. If you have a `static` member variable, all objects access that variable. If you have a `static` member function... can it be called on more than one core simultaneously? That was where this question came from, but I wanted to leave it more open for more opportunities to learn.

Comment: @musasabi "*can [a `static` member function] be called on more than one core simultaneously?*" - of course, why would you think it can't? A `static` method is practically indistinguishable from a standalone function. But, for that matter, even a non-`static` class method can be called on multiple cores at the same time, too. The only real difference between a `static` method and a non-`static` method is the hidden `this` parameter. That doesn't disqualify multiple calls to a non-`static` method from running in parallel. Class data members just have to be protected from concurrent access.

Comment: Strictly speaking, a static member function doesn't have to be compatible with a standalone `extern "C"` function, which pthreads need. In practice, however, all implementations make them compatible.

Comment: Thank you all for your contributions. I do feel as though my understanding has been improved considerably. =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> except for how much fluff you have to do to get the old and the new to play nice.

Well, in the STL, that's essentially what the `std::thread` is actually doing. If you create a thread and force it to cause a stack unwinding, and if you look at said stack, you'll see a lot of weird pointer arithmetic happening with `this` and `pthread_create` (or `CreateThread` on Windows).

That being said, it's not unusual in any way to use a `static` function of a class that then calls a `private` member of that class on an object instance, even with the `std::thread`, it really just depends on what you need those functions to do.

> does using a static member method as the start_routine argument to `pthread_create` have any undesirable side effects?

No. At least not from the perspective of functionality; that is, creating a thread on a static member won't cause any UB or crashes directly just because you are using a `static` function.

You do have to account for the fact that your operating on a static member function, but that's no different from having to account for constructors/destructors or any function of the language itself. Since this is a homework assignment, it's likely the professor is trying to teach "how things work" less than "how to use C++11".

> Would it just be better, in this case, to make `vaccine_count` public and make `count_vaccines()` a global function?

Yes and no. Having `vaccine_count` as a private member then means that `count_vaccines` must be a friend or static function, and given that `vaccine_count` seems like an "important" data point that you wouldn't want a "user of the code" inadvertently setting, it's probably better to keep it private.

You could add getters and setters, but that might complicate the code unnecessarily.

You could also just make it a public variable if you trust the users of the code to protect that variable (unlikely), and you could also just make `count_vaccines` a free/global function, but then you need to have the function after the class declaration. And if the class is a complex class (maybe has templates or some other C++ notion), then it can really complicate the code in how you operate on the class.

So yes, it could go that way, but the professor is likely trying to teach the idea of what a static function is, how threads operate on the class and how pointers work within the constructs of this exercise, among other things.

> If you have a static member variable, all objects access that variable.

That's not what `static` means in this context. The `static` keyword in C++ simply means that you do not need an object reference to call that code. So a `static` member variable can be accessed, not just by any object, but by any code, take this example:

```
class Data {
    public:
        static int x_val;
        int y_val;
};

int Data::x_val; // have to declare it since it's static


int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    Data::x_val = 10; // works because it's static.
    Data::y_val = 10; // error: accessing a non-static member
    
    Data obj;
    obj.y_val = 10; // ok because it's a member variable
    obj.x_val = 20; // this works as the complier ultimately translates this to `Data::x_val = 20`
    // BUT, referencing a static member/function on an object instance is "bad form"

    return 0;
}
```

> If you have a static member function... can it be called on more than one core simultaneously?

The `static` keyword has no effect on which core, or thread, said function is called on or if can be done in parallel.

A CPU core can only execute 1 machine level instruction per clock cycle (so essentially, just 1 assembly instruction), when a C++ program is compiled, linked and assembled, it is these "assembled" set of instructions base on the syntax you wrote that are executed on the core (or cores) of your CPU, not the `static` functions.

That static function is just an address in memory that gets called on any number of threads on any CPU core that the OS determines at any given time in your program.

Yes, you could call an OS API that pins that thread of execution calling that function to a specific core, but that's a different subject.

And for a last little bit of fun for you, on an assembly level, C++ functions basically get compiled into C-like functions (an extreme over simplification, but merely for demonstration):

**C++**

```
class Data {
    public:
        void increment() {
            this->y_val += 1024;
        }
    private:
        int y_val;
};

int main() {
    Data obj;
    obj.y_val = 42;
    obj.increment(); // obj.y_val == 1066
    return 0;
}
```

**C**

```
struct Data {
    int y_val;
};

void Data_increment(Data* this) {
    this->y_val += 1024;
}

int main() {
    Data obj;
    obj.y_val = 42;
    increment(&obj); // obj.y_val == 1066
    return 0;
}
```

Again, an over simplification, but the point is to illustrate how it all builds to assembly and what the assembly does.

Comment: Delightful. Thank you very much.